# Does returning a indirect typed object affect performance?

Tags: c++

I have an inline function

```
string myFunction() { return ""; }
```

Compared with

```
string myFunction() { return string(); }
```

does it has a performance sacrifice?

***Tested it on VC2012 release*** with std::string and QString (although on QString, the two returns different results : thanks to DaoWen). Both show the second version is about 3 times faster than the first. Thanks to all your answers and comments. Tested code is attached below

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;

inline string fa() { return ""; }
inline string fb() { return string(); }

int main()
{
    int N = 500000000;
    {
        clock_t begin = clock();
        for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
            fa();
        clock_t end = clock();
        double elapsed_secs = double(end - begin) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
        cout << "fa: " << elapsed_secs << "s \n";
    }

    {
        clock_t begin = clock();
        for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
            fb();
        clock_t end = clock();
        double elapsed_secs = double(end - begin) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
        cout << "fb: " << elapsed_secs << "s \n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: As with most performance questions: profile, and/or check the assembly.

Comment: Shouldn't do as all typing is done at compile time

Comment: are you using std::string? and if so, which stl?

Comment: I am using QString from Qt.

Comment: @Bathsheba: "Which STL?"? There is only one "STL", and there is one C++ Standard Library, and there are multiple implementations of the C++ Standard Library. Qt is not one of them.

Comment: Apologies, I meant which stl **implementation**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the example you posted, `return "";` will be automatically translated to `return string("");` *at compile time*. Unless `string("")` is significantly slower than `string()`, then there shouldn't be much of a difference.

---

In your comment you mention that you're actually using `QString`, not `std::string`. Note that `QString()` constructs a *null string* (`isNull()` and `isEmpty()` both return true), whereas `QString("")` constructs an *empty string* (`isEmpty()` returns true but `isNull()` returns false). **They're not the same thing!** You can think of `QString()` like `char * str = NULL;`, and `QString("")` like `char * str = "";`.

Answer (score 3):

They will each cause different std::string constructors.

The std::string() -- will create an empty object.

The "" will construct using std::string(char*)

The later will internally do a strlen+strcpy which is not needed in the first, so very small difference.

Comment: Well since the string literal is empty there’s at least a chance that, with proper inlining, the compiler can figure out that `strlen` will be 0 and that no copying is needed. No idea whether this is actually done though.

Answer (score 1):

Use `return string();` as that will use the default constructor. A good Standard Library implementation will probably not even initialise the string buffer at that point.

The constructor from `const char*` must take a string copy. So I think `return "";` will be slower.

But, to be really sure, *race your horses*.

Comment: I doubt it _must_ make a copy. Since it's expecting a c-style string there, it can check weather or not it's empty in a single comparison.

Comment: And it could, in theory, translate `return "";` to `return string();`.

Comment: It being what? The compiler? Surely not?

Comment: Yes, the compiler. And why not? What difference does it make for the caller?

Comment: Does the standard allow the compiler to choose which constructor to use? I'd be very surprised.

Comment: @Bathsheba: If no side effects differ, of course! What do you think optimisations do?

Comment: I mean this very specific case of empty string literal. Otherwise not, of course.

Comment: @Bathsheba - can you write a conforming program that can detect which `std::string` constructor was called? If not, the compiler can use either one.